# Could not load file or assembly 'or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c#-3.0

Hope someone could help me with this.

I'm referencing a dll proxy "MonitorProxy" in a webservice project which is hosted on a windows service host. When I debug the service host I receive this exception: 
Could not load file or assembly 'MonitorProxy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Although I'm sure that the MonitorProxy.dll is correcltly located and that the webservice reference refers to its correct location.

Any ideas??

Thank you so much in advance
Sam

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx) to view the assembly loading log and check where the web service is expecting the required dll.